# post does not give me a value when i filling dropdown from array

Tags: javascript, php

"answer" works correctly but "number" has problem

```
function add() {

    <? addToDakavebebi($_POST['answer'], $_POST['number']);?>
}
```

```
    <form method="post">
        <tr>
        <select id='number'>                                     
            <option value="">select</option>
        </select>


        <select name="answer">                                  
            <option value="">select</option>
            <option value="1">YES</option>
            <option value="2">NO</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="SAVE" onclick="add()">
        </tr>
    </form>
```

it fills box correctly on page

```
<script>
    var ddlItems = document.getElementById("number"),
        itemArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
    for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
        var opt = itemArray[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        ddlItems.appendChild(el);
    }
</script>
```

.........................................................................................................

Comment: Change id="number" to name="number". The $_POST request key is the name attribute of the given field. It needs to correspond. And also, you have no other things to select in the first dropdown (for the number).

Comment: You can't call a PHP function from JavaScript directly. You need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Add name number to the field. At the moment your server cannot grab that data

```
<select id='number' name='number'>                                     
    <option value="">select</option>
</select>
```